# Gcode for fabric cutting machine

Tags: g-code

i am trying to understand how following gcode works:

```
H1*
G71*
M70*
M20*
Default Table*
N1*
D2*
M15*
X115Y150S*X115Y461S*2322513151*
D2*
M15*
X185Y171S*X185Y420S*21115351*
D2*
M15*
X255Y234S*X255Y297S*17*
D2*
M15*
X184Y205*
M14*
X184Y305*
X284Y305*
X284Y205*
X184Y205*
M15*
M0*
```

I tried to use Gcode viewer. Here is how it looks:

[image: gcode]

Basically it must be square 10x10 mm.

According to my information it must be [Standard Gerber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerber_format#Standard_Gerber_(revoked)) format. The old format, revoked by the developer. There are not much [information](http://www.idea2ic.com/File_Formats/GERBER.pdf) about it, but mostly i understand meaning of all operations. Except for two places:

- If you look in file you can find strange moves like `X115Y150S*X115Y461S*2322513151*`. Particularly i don't understand the meaning of `S` at the end of coordinates, plus stange number in next section after `*`. For me it looks like *fast travel* command. But usually Gcode has different codes for such an operation.
- Also, probably because i am new to this, i don't understand meaning of preparation moves. Why they make this hook and not approach directly to place to cut the square?

Comment: are you sure this G-code is valid? what [dialect](https://www.reddit.com/r/CNC/comments/b9xsal/many_dialects_of_gcode/) is it? What is your machine-controller? I have never seen a number ending in asterisk `*` inside a G-code!

Comment: This code produced by Optitex for Gerber cutter. What i know for sure is that such files work.

Comment: 1. The S is the spindle speed 2. The asterisks `*` is to do with checksum, I have no idea what it is 3. G-code is very machine specific you can't necessarily use a g-code developed for a different machine. try to use [webgcode](https://nraynaud.github.io/webgcode/) and / or [CAMotics](https://camotics.org/) to simulate the process.

Comment: Yes, i also think this can be a checksum. But why does it have different lengths?

Comment: This as far as my limited knowledge helps, I would suggest to take a look at [other forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285839/where-can-i-ask-about-cnc-machines/304519#304519) and try posting your question in any of [those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285839/where-can-i-ask-about-cnc-machines/304519#304519) as well.